# How does one disable Office Web Apps for a given Site Collection or Web Application?

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

A customer has a farm with multiple web apps, one of which is accessible anonymously.  Office Web Apps is installed on the farm.  On the anonymous site, Word documents open in the browser viewer, but the 'Open in Word' button is disabled.  In addition, there is no Send to -> Download option on the library items.  The customer would like the default behavior on the anonymous site to be similar to any other website: Word documents are downloaded where the user may open them locally.  Is it possible to disable Office Web Apps for this web application or site collection only?

Note we have disabled the OWA site collection feature, and experimented with variations of that and 'OpenInClient'  but Word documents still open in OWA for anonymous users, regardless of any setting on those two.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe you should disable OWA until this is sorted due to licences. Afaik every user that uses OWA needs to have an Office licence, if not MS might not be to happy about this setup :)

Comment: By "disable the OWA site collection feature" do you mean the Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature?

Comment: Had the same problem, even after deactivating the OWA feature and enabling the openinclient feature, OWA was still the default. PS, licensing is not really a problem, anyone who owns an Office license gets an OWA license with it. So if you have Office on your own computer, technically you are allowed to use OWA too :-D

Comment: Yeah, everyone that has Office, but how can you guarantee this when its anonymous access? Probably it wont be an issue, companies usually sorts it out before MS comes on a visit for counting.

Comment: Licensing is taken care of. @David  By 'OWA site collection feature', I mean 'Office Web Apps'  'OpenInClient' refers to 'Open Documents in Client Apps By Default'.  The issue is that, regardless of any combination of enabling/disabling those features, Word docs still appear in OWA on an anonymous site.

Comment: "anyone who owns an Office license gets an OWA license with it" If you read the license terms, I believe it's anyone with an "Enterprise" Office license gets an OWA license. Not all Office licenses are created equal.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific than that.  It needs to be an Office 2010 license, and I believe its Office 2010 Professional.  Lower levels of Office would not be included.  In addition, external users and internet users are not supposed to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I did test this the other day, I had to run a PowerShell-script to get it deactivated right.

```
$webAppsFeatureId = $(Get-SPFeature -limit all | where {$_.displayname -eq "OfficeWebApps"}).Id 
$singleSiteCollection = Get-SPSite -Identity http://<site_name> 
Disable-SPFeature $webAppsFeatureId -Url $singleSiteCollection.URL
```

It did throw an error when I first tried to deactivate from the GUI. You could try this, not sure if it will work in your case.

Comment: This will deactivate the feature, but in some cases, Office Web Apps will still attempt to display the document even with the feature disabled.  Specifically if SP is unable to use client integration- as in anonymous sites and non IE browsers.

Comment: This script appears on a TechNet page, I'm not sure which is the original source ;) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837418(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the site collection perspective, you can disable the Office Web Apps Feature. This will disable the functionality for the site collection.

Comment: That's essentially what the powershell script Anders provided does.  But, as noted there, even with that feature disabled, documents can open in the browser.  This is especially a problem in anonymous sites or with non-ie browsers where SharePoint cannot detect Office.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Custom List attachments. Setting the feature `OpenInClient` on only makes IE to open documents in local application, but Chrome still tries to open WOPI pages.

I fixed this issue by using javascript (In the list item view form -> Edit Page -> Edit Webpart -> JS Link) to remove the attachment links' `onmousemouse` and `onclick` so it does not redirects to WOPI server:

```js
var attachmentTable = document.getElementById('idAttachmentsTable');
      jQuery('tr a', attachmentTable).each(function(index, ele: HTMLAnchorElement) {
        ele.removeAttribute('onmousedown');
        ele.removeAttribute('onclick');
      });
```